# daemon running for several hours, and dies

Tags: lighttpd, daemon, monit

After restart server, this is running:

`PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

19653 lighttpd  16   0 67584  39m  16m R 21.3 15.3   0:17.60 php-cgi

 8006 mysql     15   0  137m  22m 4800 S  5.3  8.8   1:07.91 mysqld

13364 lighttpd  16   0 63560  39m  20m S  2.3 15.3   0:34.57 php-cgi

    1 root      15   0  2068  648  556 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.55 init

 1741 root      15   0  2196 1012  816 R  0.0  0.4   0:00.01 top

 7449 root      15  -4  2152  552  344 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 udevd

 7839 root      15   0  1724  608  512 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 syslogd

 7888 root      18   0  7024 1056  660 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 sshd

 7899 root      18   0  2724  872  700 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 xinetd

 7934 root      18   0  3616 1288 1116 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 mysqld_safe

11499 root      18   0  9180 1676  660 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.03 sendmail

13330 smmsp     20   0  8132 1472  608 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.00 sendmail

13344 lighttpd  15   0  6792 2732  756 S  0.0  1.0   0:01.30 lighttpd

13347 lighttpd  21   0 47144 8984 6168 S  0.0  3.4   0:00.09 php-cgi

13356 lighttpd  15   0 47144 8984 6168 S  0.0  3.4   0:00.09 php-cgi

13358 lighttpd  15   0 68128  43m  20m S  0.0 17.0   0:08.42 php-cgi

13360 lighttpd  21   0 47144 8988 6168 S  0.0  3.4   0:00.08 php-cgi

13365 lighttpd  15   0 47144 8992 6168 S  0.0  3.4   0:00.09 php-cgi

13446 root      18   0  4408 1108  560 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 crond

13669 xfs       18   0  3456 1180  728 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 xfs

13681 root      18   0  5580  708  428 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 saslauthd

13682 root      18   0  5580  444  164 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 saslauthd

13767 root      15   0  7496 5432 1604 S  0.0  2.1   0:00.03 miniserv.pl

21715 lighttpd  16   0 78908  49m  15m S  0.0 19.2   0:16.40 php-cgi

32674 root      18   0 10016 2828 2284 S  0.0  1.1   0:00.03 sshd

32747 root      15   0  3752 1536 1236 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.02 bash`

but after several hours, it will become like this:

`PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

    1 root      15   0  2068  656  556 S  0.0  0.3   0:03.89 init

 3723 root      15   0  4408 1112  564 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.16 crond

 9220 root      18   0  9860 2828 2288 S  0.0  1.1   0:00.08 sshd

 9688 root      15   0  3752 1540 1236 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.11 bash

10210 root      15   0  2196 1004  816 R  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 top

21529 root      15   0  1724  608  512 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.19 syslogd

21602 root      18   0  7024 1052  660 S  0.0  0.4   0:13.52 sshd

21623 root      18   0  2724  868  700 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 xinetd

21717 mysql     15   0  138m  24m 4988 S  0.0  9.4  79:19.17 mysqld`

This will happen over and over again.. The webmin also dies

**Im using:**

-CentOS 5.3

-lighttpd

`"max-procs" => 1

"PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "6"

"PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "500"`

-PHP
use eaccelerator

-monit
 monit error in respawn: `Id "mo" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes`
monit code in inittab: `mo:234:respawn:/usr/bin/monit -Ic /etc/monit.d/monitrc`

I also dont know how to fix monit error in inittab

Before this, nothing like this happen when the server running with below config:
-default mod_fastcgi config
-without monit

So, I start use monit because lighttpd dies when Im sleeping and also my website a bit slow, plus high RAM usage on php-cgi (My RAM only 256MB, host more than 20 websites in it)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running afoul of the out-of-memory killer.

Increase the amount of RAM in the server, or if not possible, increase swap.

I'm a little surprised you can get CentOS 5.3 to do anything useful with so little memory.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your `FCGI_CHILDREN` to zero. This is recommended for newer lighttpd versions. Set more `max-procs` instead. Try tweaking the number of max-procs. If your site is not hammered all the time, just having 2 will be more than enough.

Comment: Im using eAccelerator, which many people suggest me to set the "max-procs" value to "1" because every proc has their own bytecode cache